# Significant Figures Formatting.00

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, formatting

I wrote this for an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299942/c-stdsetprecision-in-c-sharp/32300200#32300200) on formatting numbers to specific quantities of significant figures (after all, [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel)), anyway, all critiques welcome.

It's pretty easy to use, `FormatSignificantFigures(0.123, 2)` should return `0.12`; `FormatSignificantFigures(0.123, 5)` should return `0.12300`; `FormatSignificantFigures(0.123456, 5)` should return `0.12346`, etc.

```
public static string FormatSignificantFigures(double number, int figures)
{
    int e = 0;

    while (number >= 10.0)
    {
        e += 1;
        number /= 10;
    }

    while (number < 1.0)
    {
        e -= 1;
        number *= 10;
    }

    figures--;

    number = Math.Round(number, figures);

    figures += 0 - e;
    while (e > 0)
    {
        number *= 10;
        e -= 1;
    }

    while (e < 0)
    {
        number /= 10;
        e += 1;
    }

    if (figures < 0)
    {
        figures = 0;
    }

    return number.ToString($"f{figures}");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int e = 0;
> ```

You're initializing `e` to `default(int)`, which is redundant. This would be enough:

```
int e;
```

I'm not quite sure why you're incrementing `e` like this:

> ```
> while (number >= 10.0)
> {
>     e += 1;
>     number /= 10;
> }
> ```

Why not just `e++;`?

And same thing here:

> ```
> while (e > 0)
> {
>     number *= 10;
>     e -= 1;
> }
> ```

There's `e--;` to *decrement*.

But you know this already:

> ```
> figures--;
> ```

Why? Why are you using both `-= 1` and `--` in the same method?

> ```
> figures += 0 - e;
> ```

Looks like a pretty convoluted way to do `figures -= e;`.

And then we get to the return value...

> ```
> return number.ToString($"f{figures}");
> ```

You're using C# 6.0 string interpolation here. A *format string*. The SO question you linked to has an accepted answer that uses a format string to do *all the work*: it seems `string.Format("{0:G10}", number)` would do the formatting part just right - I'd parameterize the length by making a method that builds a format string from the parameter (something like `"{0:G" + digits + "}"`), and uses that format string to return the formatted string.

I think it would be easier to read and to follow, than the whole logic you got there.

Or, don't use a format string. IMO using a formatted string here defeats the purpose of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Damn, I must have been *really* tired to make that many mistakes...lol Although I wrote this *long* before the other SO answer was posted, which is why I used `f` instead of `G`.